# R: Calculation combinations and variable iteration for loop

Tags: r

I want to calculate combinations in R.

I want to calculate and get results as in the below code, but in my code, the number in the for loop depends on the number of variables (e.g., `length(ncomb)`).

How do I set the number in a for loop?
Or is there a better way to calculate the combinations that I want?

```
#Block
nblock = c(1,2,3)
num_nblock = length(nblock)

#Position
tol = c(1:6)
total = length(tol)


#Calculate number of Combination
#6C1*5C2*3C3
t1 = total
ncomb=c()
for (i in 1:num_nblock) {
  ncomb[i] = choose(t1,nblock[i])
  t1 = t1-nblock[i]
}


#Calculate Combination
Clist = data.frame()

for (i in 1:ncomb[1]) {
  comb1 = combn(total,nblock[1])
  remain = setdiff(tol,comb1[,i])  
  
  for (j in 1:ncomb[2]) {
    comb2 = combn(remain,nblock[2])
    remain2 = setdiff(remain,comb2[,j])
    
    for (k in 1:ncomb[3]) {
      comb3 = combn(remain2,nblock[3])
      
      ans = c(comb1[,i],comb2[,j],comb3[,k])
      Clist =rbind(Clist,ans)
      
    }
    
  }
}
```

```
#Result :Clist
   X1L X2L X3L X4L X5L X6L
1    1   2   3   4   5   6
2    1   2   4   3   5   6
3    1   2   5   3   4   6
4    1   2   6   3   4   5
5    1   3   4   2   5   6
6    1   3   5   2   4   6
7    1   3   6   2   4   5
8    1   4   5   2   3   6
9    1   4   6   2   3   5
10   1   5   6   2   3   4
.....
50   5   4   6   1   2   3
51   6   1   2   3   4   5
52   6   1   3   2   4   5
53   6   1   4   2   3   5
54   6   1   5   2   3   4
55   6   2   3   1   4   5
56   6   2   4   1   3   5
57   6   2   5   1   3   4
58   6   3   4   1   2   5
59   6   3   5   1   2   4
60   6   4   5   1   2   3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is an idea I have which may be harder to understand but solves your problem of having a variable number of for loops.

Before I show my code, let me explain the idea using your example of **dividing 1 through 6** into **blocks of 1, 2, and 3**. As you said we can calculate the total number of combinations as 6C1*5C2*3C3=60. Now the question is how to fill up the 60 entries.

So if you think about a tree from Block 1 to 3, each branch of Block 1 correspond to 5C2 number of branches of Block2, and each branch of Block 2 correspond to 3C3 branch of Block 3. In this way, the total number of branches will be 6C1*5C2*3C3=60. Essentially how you wanna fill up the output matrix is to repeat each branch in Block 1 5C2*3C3 times, each branch in Block 2 3C3 time, and each branch in Block 3 should appear uniquely. To summarize you want to repeat each branch the number of times to the **"cardinality"** of Blocks to the right hand side.

This is what the following code is doing.

```
# ++++ Using your example and initialization ++++
# Block
nblock = c(1,2,3)
num_nblock = length(nblock)

# Position
tol = c(1:6)
total = length(tol)

t1 = total
ncomb=c()
for (i in 1:num_nblock) {
  ncomb[i] = choose(t1,nblock[i])
  t1 = t1-nblock[i]
}
# ++++++++

# Initialize result matrix
Clist = matrix(nrow = prod(ncomb), ncol = total)

# Block col ID: produce list of (1),(2,3),(4,5,6) as col ID of output matrix
block_cols = list()
start = 1
for (i in 1:num_nblock) {
  block_cols[[i]] = start:(start+nblock[i]-1)
  start = start + nblock[i]
}

# Fill the output matrix: iterate each (row,block) of matrix
for (i in 1:prod(ncomb)) {
  for (j in 1:num_nblock) {

    # First col ID of each block. In this example, always 1, 2, 4
    block_first_col_id = block_cols[[j]][1]

    # Fill the pos when its still NA
    if (is.na(Clist[i, block_first_col_id])) {

      # Filler is all combination having removed numbers appeared in left blocks
      remain = setdiff(tol, Clist[i, 0:(block_first_col_id-1)])
      com = combn(remain, nblock[j])

      # Key step: replicate to fill remaining cardinality
      filler = apply(com, 1, function(x) rep(x, each = prod(ncomb[(j+1):length(ncomb)])))
      
      # Store filler to output.
      # Filler may be a vector, in which case dim will return NULL
      filler_nrow = ifelse(is.null(dim(filler)[1]), 1, dim(filler)[1])
      Clist[i:(i + filler_nrow - 1), block_cols[[j]]] = filler

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your useful code. It is my great help. @Yuan Yin